# Comparing lines in 2 files in Java

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to compare 2 files, line by line. After this comparison is made, all lines are copied to a 3rd file and they are identified as "present in both files"; "exclusive of fileA"; or "exclusive of fileB".  Thanks to the help of @nono and @Andreas my code is running, but nothing is being written on the output file yet.

```
       public static void compareFileLines(String fileLocA, String fileLocB, String fileLocC) throws IOException{
        //fileLoc'X' is the filepath 
        try{
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fileLocA));
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fileLocB));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(fileLocC));

        String []linesA = new String [fileLenght(fileLocA)];  //filelenght checks number of lines on a file
        String []linesB = new String [fileLenght(fileLocB)];

        for (int i=0; i< linesA.length-1; i++){
        linesA[i]=  reader1.readLine();
        }
        for (int i=0; i< linesB.length-1; i++){
             linesB[i]=  reader2.readLine();
        }
        boolean finder = false;         
        for (int n =0; n<linesA.length-1; n++){
            for(int m=0; m<linesB.length-1; m++){
                if (linesA[n].equals(linesB[m])){
                    finder = true;
                    writer.append(linesA[n]+" Is in both files \n");
                }
                if (finder == false){
                    writer.append(linesA[n]+ "Is exclusive of File1");                      
            }
                finder = false;
        }
        }
        finder = false;
        for (int n=0; n< linesB.length -1; n++){
            for (int m=0; m< linesA.length -1; m++){
                if (linesB[n].equals(linesA[m])){
                    finder = true;
                }

            }
            if (finder == false){
                writer.append(linesB[n] +" is exclusive of File2");
            }
            finder = false;
        }


    }finally{           

    }       

}
```

Comment: Call `hasNextLine()` before calling `nextLine()`. `nextLine()` does not return null at EOF like `BufferedReader.readLine()` does. Since you're only doing line reading, switch to `BufferedReader`, because it performs *much* better than `Scanner`.

Comment: ... and do **not** compare String objects with `==`, use `equals()` method instead

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I did as you guys said, I used bufferedReader instead but it says that is expecting a Reader object instead of File (the constructor bufferedReader(File) is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

The BufferedReader constructor can accept a FilReader.
The FileReader can accept a file or the path.

FileReader fr = new FileReader("text.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

To loop use :
String s; 
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { 
...
}